# NullpointerException when called alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want call alertdialog in my application and getting error

```
"12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Activity.getVolumeControlStream(Activity.java:3714)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Dialog.setOwnerActivity(Dialog.java:188)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2494)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Activity.onPrepareDialog(Activity.java:2518)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2568)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2527)
12-02 09:40:07.500: E/AndroidRuntime(4693):     at com.example.ok1.ToDoCalendarViewMaker$2.onItemLongClick(ToDoCalendarViewMaker.java:170)"
```

source code:

```
public class ToDoCalendarViewMaker extends SherlockFragmentActivity  implements OnItemLongClickListener {
//final String Tag="States";

public  ToDoCalendarViewMaker() {

}   

public  void makeGrid(Context context, View view, final MyCalendar myCalendar) {
    final String Tag="States"; 
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4");
       GridView myGridView;

       final Context myContext;
       final Context myContext1;
       View myView;



       myView = view;

       myContext = context;

       myGridView = (GridView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);


       String[] from = { "text", "background" };

       int[] to = { R.id.tvDay, R.id.llDay };

       ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> myData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

       myData = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) myCalendar.myData.clone();



       SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(myContext,

                    myData, R.layout.day_layout, from, to);
       Log.d(Tag, "до биндера");

       sAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
       Log.d(Tag, "после");

       myGridView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

       myGridView.setNumColumns(7);

       myGridView.setVerticalSpacing(5);

       myGridView.setHorizontalSpacing(5);

       myGridView.setOnTouchListener(new MyGridOnTouchListener());



       myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             @Override

             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id){
                 Log.d(Tag, "сработал onItemClick= "+ MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick);
                 if (MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick == true) {
                     Log.d(Tag, "идем в лист задач ");   
                 //*********работа с БД****************
                    // создаем объект для данных
                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(myContext);    
                        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                        //*********работа с БД****************  
                       // Toast.makeText(myContext,

                     //   "" + myCalendar.returnDateById(position) + " + " + id,

                    //    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
                       String id_for_listtsk=myCalendar.returnDateById(position).toString();
                        //добавляем строку в БД
                        cv.put("data_id", myCalendar.returnDateById(position));
                     //  long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
                        Log.d(Tag, "row inserted, ID = ");
                        Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    //   logCursor(c);
                        dbHelper.close();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, ListTsk.class);
                        Log.d(Tag, "==== "+id_for_listtsk);
                        intent.putExtra("dat", id_for_listtsk.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("currentPagerList", "1");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       // Context myContext1=myContext.getApplicationContext();
                        myContext.startActivity(intent);
                     //   return false;
                        //************************
                     //   ToDoCalendarActivity.this.finish();
                 }
                 }

            private void logCursor(Cursor c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String Tag="States";

                if (c!=null) {
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String str;
                        do {
                            str="";
                            for (String cn: c.getColumnNames()) {
                                str = str.concat(cn + " = " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
                            }
                            Log.d(Tag, str);
                        } while (c.moveToNext());

                    } 
                }



            }


       });

       myGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Log.d(Tag, "11111111111111");
            String id_for_listtsk=myCalendar.returnDateById(position).toString();

            /*
             * вызываем диалог
             */
            int dialogId = 0;
            dialogId = DialogFactory.DIALOG_TASKS;
            //ToDoCalendarActivity.showDial(dialogId);//showDialog(dialogId);
            showDialog(dialogId);
            //***
            return true;
        }});

       //sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}




@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
//      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//      imm.showSoftInput(dialogButtonedit1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    return DialogFactory.getDialogById(id, ToDoCalendarActivity.context);//this
}


public static Dialog createCustomAlertTasks(final Context context) {
    //Dialog dialog2=null;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);





    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customnew, null);
    builder.setView(layout);
    Dialog dialog2 = builder.setTitle("Введите новый список")
            .create();

    return dialog2;
}


@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    return false;
}



}

//********************************************************
class MyViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {
      int p;
  @Override

 public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,

              String textRepresentation) {

       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       int i;

       switch (view.getId()) {

       // LinearLayout

       case R.id.llDay:

              i = ((Integer) data).intValue();

              if (i == -1)

                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.another_day);

              else if (i == 0)

                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day);

              else if (i == 1)

                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.weekend);

              else if (i == 2)

                  p=4;//view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.today_another_day);

              else if (i == 3)

                  view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.today_day);

              else if (i == 4)

                  p=6;//view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.today_weekend);

              return true;

       }

       return false;

 }     

}

class MyGridOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{


  final String Tag="States";
  @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent) {
      Log.d(Tag, "сработал онтач.....");
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick=false;
       if (paramMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              Log.d(Tag, "опустил палец");
              ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
              Log.d(Tag, "x1="+String.valueOf(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1));
              ToDoCalendarActivity.touchY1 = paramMotionEvent.getY();

              ToDoCalendarActivity.flag = true;

       }



       if (paramMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {


              ToDoCalendarActivity.touchY2 = paramMotionEvent.getY();

       }



       if (paramMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
           Log.d(Tag, "x2="+String.valueOf(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2));
                Log.d(Tag, "Поднял палец");
                if (ToDoCalendarActivity.flag==true &&

        Math.abs(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2 - ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1)>

         Math.abs(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchY2 - ToDoCalendarActivity.touchY1)){

          if (ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2>ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1){
              if ((ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1)>50) {
                  ToDoCalendarActivity.prevMonth();  
              }
              else if (((ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1)<10)) {
                  MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick=true;
            }
           Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1));
           ToDoCalendarActivity.flag=false;

         } else {
        Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2));
        if ((ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2)>50) {
          ToDoCalendarActivity.nextMonth();  
      }
        else if (((ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1-ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2)<10)) {
          MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick=true;
        }       
        ToDoCalendarActivity.flag=false;
         }

                                          }
           //   ToDoCalendarActivity.flag = false;

       }
       Log.d(Tag, "....................");
      if (ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX1==ToDoCalendarActivity.touchX2){
          Log.d(Tag, "Значения равны");
          MainActivity.MyFlag_onClick=true;  
      }

       return false;

 }

}
```

---

```
public static Dialog getDialogById(int id, final Context context) {

    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ALERT:

        //dialog = createAlertDialog(context);
        break;
    case DIALOG_PROGRESS:

        //dialog = createProgressDialog(context);
        break;
    case DIALOG_INPUT:

    //  dialog = Lists.createInputAlert(context);
        dialog = Lists.createCustomAlertNew(context);
        break;
    case DIALOG_CUSTOM:

        dialog = Lists.createCustomAlert(context);

        break;  
    case DIALOG_TASKS:

        dialog = ToDoCalendarViewMaker.createCustomAlertTasks(context);

        break;  
    }
    return dialog;
}


}
```

---

```
public class ToDoCalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private KillReceiver mKillReceiver;
final String Tag="States"; 
static private View[] views = new View[3];  
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "accountName";
static MyCalendar[] cArray = new MyCalendar[3];

static ViewFlipper vf;

static int currentView;

View mainView;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
int REQUEST_CODE = 11223344;

static ToDoCalendarViewMaker toDoCalendarViewMaker;
static float touchX1,touchX2,touchY1,touchY2;

static boolean flag;
static int bb = 0;
static Context context;

static TextView myTextView;
static final String SOME_ACTION = "com.BAO.OK1.SOME_ACTION";

TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[7];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */





@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //       if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finish_cal", true)) {
    //          
    //           finish();
    //       }
    //       Log.d(Tag, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!финализируем календарь"+getIntent().getBooleanExtra("finish_cal", true));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_layout);
    //     Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого");
    //кнопки отвечающие за переход по месяцам
    Log.d(Tag, "Пытаемся запустить календарь");
    View prevButton = findViewById(R.id.prev_button);

    prevButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //останавливаем AlarmManager
            try {
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent_stop_alarm = new Intent(MainActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
                alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent_stop_alarm, 0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

    //*******************пытаемся навешать слушатель для закрытия активити
    Log.d(Tag, "Пытаемся запустить календарь");
    mKillReceiver = new KillReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mKillReceiver,intentFilter);
    Log.d(Tag, "Пытаемся запустить календарь1");
    //******************************************************************


    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    context = getApplicationContext();


    //      Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого 2");
    LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){

        views[i] = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null, false);

    }


    //      Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  3");
    mainView = findViewById(R.id.mainll);
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  3.1");
    cArray[0] = new MyCalendar();
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  3ю2");
    cArray[1] = new MyCalendar();
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  3ю3");
    cArray[2] = new MyCalendar();
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  3ю4");
    Resources res = getResources();



    MyCalendar.setNamesOfDays(

            res.getString(R.string.Mon),

            res.getString(R.string.Tue),

            res.getString(R.string.Wed),

            res.getString(R.string.Thu),

            res.getString(R.string.Fri),

            res.getString(R.string.Sat),

            res.getString(R.string.Sun));

    MyCalendar.setNamesOfMonths(

            res.getString(R.string.January),

            res.getString(R.string.February),

            res.getString(R.string.March),

            res.getString(R.string.April),

            res.getString(R.string.May),

            res.getString(R.string.June),

            res.getString(R.string.July),

            res.getString(R.string.August),

            res.getString(R.string.September),

            res.getString(R.string.October),

            res.getString(R.string.November),

            res.getString(R.string.December));

    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4");

    cArray[0].setState();
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4/0");

    cArray[1].setState();

    cArray[2].setState();

    cArray[1].nextMonth();
     toDoCalendarViewMaker = new ToDoCalendarViewMaker();
    cArray[2].prevMonth();
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4/1");
    toDoCalendarViewMaker.makeGrid(this, views[0], cArray[0]);
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4/1\1");
    toDoCalendarViewMaker.makeGrid(this, views[1], cArray[1]);
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4/1.2");
    toDoCalendarViewMaker.makeGrid(this, views[2], cArray[2]);
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  4/1.3");

    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  5");
    vf.addView((View) views[0]);

    vf.addView((View) views[1]);

    vf.addView((View) views[2]);

    currentView = 0;

    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);

    textViewArray[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textData);

    textViewArray[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    textViewArray[2] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    textViewArray[3] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    textViewArray[4] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    textViewArray[5] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

    textViewArray[6] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    // рисуем названия дней недели          
    Log.d(Tag, "ljokj до сюдого  6");
    int j = MyCalendar.beforeFirstDay;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        if (j == 7) {

            j = 0;

        }

        textViewArray[i].setText(MyCalendar.namesOfDays[j]);

        j++;

    }

    // рисуем текущую дату посредине

    myTextView.setText(cArray[currentView].getMonthName() + " "

       + Integer.toString(cArray[currentView].getYear()));

}     

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d(Tag, "onClick");   

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.prev_button:

        prevMonth();

        break;

    case R.id.next_button:                 

        nextMonth();

        break;

    }           

}

//****
public static void nextMonth(){

    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.next_appear));

    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.next_disappear));

    vf.showNext();

    int prevView = currentView - 1;

    if (prevView == -1) prevView = 2;

    currentView++;

    if (currentView == 3) currentView = 0;              

    cArray[prevView].nextMonth();

    cArray[prevView].nextMonth();

    cArray[prevView].nextMonth();

    toDoCalendarViewMaker.makeGrid(context, views[prevView], cArray[prevView]);     

    // рисуем текущую дату посредине

    myTextView.setText(cArray[currentView].getMonthName() + " "

     + Integer.toString(cArray[currentView].getYear()));

}



public static void prevMonth(){      
    //  Log.d(Tag, "предыдущий месяц");
    vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.next_appear_1)); 
    vf.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.next_disappear_1));

    vf.showPrevious();

    int nextView = currentView + 1;

    if (nextView == 3) nextView = 0;

    currentView--;

    if (currentView == -1) currentView = 2;             

    cArray[nextView].prevMonth();

    cArray[nextView].prevMonth();

    cArray[nextView].prevMonth();

    toDoCalendarViewMaker.makeGrid(context, views[nextView], cArray[nextView]);           

    // рисуем текущую дату посредине

    myTextView.setText(cArray[currentView].getMonthName() + " "

     + Integer.toString(cArray[currentView].getYear()));

}


@Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(Tag, "onTouchEvent ToDoCalendarActivity");
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        touchX1 = event.getX();
        Log.d(Tag, "x1="+String.valueOf(touchX1));
        touchY1 = event.getY();

        flag = true;

    }     

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        touchX2 = event.getX();
        Log.d(Tag, "x2="+String.valueOf(touchX2));

        touchY2 = event.getY();

        if (flag==true && Math.abs(touchX2 - touchX1)>Math.abs(touchY2 - touchY1)){

            if (touchX2>touchX1) {
                Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(touchX2-touchX1));
                prevMonth();flag=false;

            } else {
                Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(touchX1-touchX2));
                nextMonth();flag=false;

            }

        }

    }     

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        flag = false;

    }     

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
//*****
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Today");
    //  menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Убрать выполненные");
    menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Exit");
    //        menu.add(1, 4, 1, "copy");
    //        menu.add(1, 5, 2, "paste");
    //        menu.add(1, 6, 4, "exit");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;
}



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    //  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        ListTsk.id_for_listtsk=null;
        onDestroy();
        break;
        //  case 2:
        //      
        //      break;
    case 3:
        //this.onDestroy();
        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        myintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        myintent.putExtra("finish", true);

        startActivity(myintent);
        onDestroy();
        //      break;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // закрываем подключение при выходе
    try {
        //******************************пробуем засунуть сюда настройки
        SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nastrPreferences = settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
        //*******************************

        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceUpdate.class).putExtra("preferences", nastrPreferences));
        Log.d(Tag, "запустили службу ServiceUpdate");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    Log.d(Tag, "todocalendarActivity: onDestroy()");

    finish();

    //   db.close();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
        Log.d(Tag, "todocalendarActivity: onStop()");
    //  finish();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    //this.dbHelper.close();
        Log.d(Tag, "todocalendarActivity: onPause()");
}

public static void showDial(int num) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "hello", 1000).show();
    bb++;
//  showDialog(num);
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //  Log.d(Tag, "Была нажата кнопка возврат");
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(100);
    return;
} 
private final class KillReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

may be I have error in raw "return DialogFactory.getDialogById(id, ToDoCalendarActivity.context)" ? May be I must use other context? help me please

Comment: better u can debug to find crash cause.

Comment: yes you need to pass return DialogFactory.getDialogById(id, myContext);

Comment: please post the code where you see the crash, dont expect us to go through this much